# python using string index 2d bool array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am looking for easy way to maintain 2d bool array(True/False, Y/N or 0/1) with string index.

For ex. result array as follow:

```
     AA BB CC DD <- Columns
    -------------
EE | Y  N  Y  Y
FF | N  N  N  Y
GG | Y  Y  N  N
```

and get value with sting index like val = result['CC']['EE']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dict ?

`{"EE" : {"AA" : "Y", "BB":"N", "CC":"Y", "DD":"Y"}}`

Or create classes with **getitem** overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enums and declare the values of AA, BB, CC and so on.....

For Enums, refer this  https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: you can give some meaningful names to rows and columns also through enums.